# Better edge detection with OpenCV and rounded corner cards

Tags: python, opencv

I've been using the great tutorials at [PyImageSearch.com](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/05/05/building-pokedex-python-opencv-perspective-warping-step-5-6/) to get a Pi (v3) to recognise some playing cards. So far it's been working out alright, but the method described in the tutorials is meant more for sharp-cornered rectangles, and of course playing cards are round-cornered. This means that the contour corners end up being drawn slightly offset to the actual card, so the cropped and de-warped image I get is slightly rotated, which throws off the phash recognition slightly. [image]
The green outline is that provided by OpenCV, and you can see compared to the red lines I drew that mark the actual boundaries that it's offset/rotated. My question is; how can I get it to follow those red lines i.e. detect the edges?

This is the code currently running to get that result:

```js
frame = vs.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=640)
    image = frame.copy() #copy frame so that we don't get funky contour problems when drawing contours directly onto the frame.
    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17) 
    edges = imutils.auto_canny(gray)

    cv2.imshow("Edge map", edges)

    #find contours in the edged image, keep only the largest
    # ones, and initialize our screen contour
    _, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:3]
    screenCnt = None

    # loop over our contours
    for c in cnts:
        # approximate the contour
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.05 * peri, True)
     
        # if our approximated contour has four points, then
        # we can assume that we have found our card
        if len(approx) == 4:
            screenCnt = approx
            break

    cv2.drawContours(image, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to read the [OpenCV contour docs](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) a bit more. What I was basically looking for was a minimum area box around my contour:

```
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt) # get a rectangle rotated to have minimal area
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect) # get the box from the rectangle
box = np.int0(box) # the box is now the new contour.
```

In my case, all instances of `screenCnt` now become the `box` variable and the rest of my code continues as normal.

Comment: How do you cope with perspective distortion?

Comment: @IronWaffleMan Can you please elaborate where exactly this code needs to go because i get an error if i drop this three lines just before `cv2.drawContours`.

Answer (score -1):

if you are finding about how to make rectangle's border edges Sharpe in open cv python so I have an idea first you need to make a square which dimensions are 100x100 and then make another rectangle on canter of first rectangle which dimensions are 90x90 now the border of rectangle you see it is 10px and there is Sharpe rectangle's border edges.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).